# What is the return type of nodemailer's transporter.sendMail()?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, nodemailer

I got this piece of code:

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp...",
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  requireTLS: true,
  auth: {...}
});

const result = await transporter.sendMail({
  from: "XXX",
  to: "YYY",
  subject: "ZZZ",
  text: "WWW"
});
```

Typescript is currently evaluation the `result` as `any`.

[image]

Is this correct?

I have also installed `@types/nodemailer`. This is the type definition contained in it:

[image]

Even if I try to type it as `SentMessageInfo` directly, I also get `any`:

```
import { SentMessageInfo } from "nodemailer";

const result: SentMessageInfo = await transporter.sendMail({...});
```

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Or there is really no type definition for that?

The type for `transporter` seems to be correct (the type is `Mail`).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type is correct, [`SentMessageInfo` is simply an alias for `any`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/nodemailer/index.d.ts#L22):

```typescript
export type SentMessageInfo = any;
```